# How to properly load multiple properties file in Spring from different locations?

Tags: java, spring

As I can see there were plenty questions regarding properties in Spring already asked, but what I want to achieve is a little unusal.

Let assume that I have `cp.prop.file.properties` on the classpath

```
external.prop.file.path=file:./path/to/external.prop.file.properties
```

Now if in my spring context I will declare something like this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:cp.prop.file.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder location="${external.prop.file.path}" />
```

I suppose it will not work properly. I do not have possibility to check at the moment.

I believe my intentions on what I am trying to achive are fairly clear. In general, I want to have some properties that are build dependet and are not configurable and some that configurable and are externalized. And the path to the latter is defined during build.

Comment: Try giving `"order"` attribute to your placeholder configurer. First one as `order=1`, and second one as `order=2`?

Comment: *"I suppose it will not work properly. I do not have possibility to check at the moment."* Why not ask **after** you've tried, then?

Comment: kryger - perhaps I was too euphemistic. I am 99% sure that it won't work that way. Rohit Jain - thanks for the hint I'll try that

Comment: It didn't work **Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
 [/${external.props}]** The property has not been resolved

Answer (score 2):

You can load more than one property file with following syntax

```
    <context:property-placeholder 
               location="classpath:a.properties, file:/path/to/myConfigFile.properties"
               ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Comment: It won't work the way I want it to. Bear in mind that path:/to/file is read as a property from the first file, so it have to be resolved before.

Answer (score 1):

Use on from following solution

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:core-application.properties,
              classpath:core-services.properties,
              classpath:core-messages.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

or

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:core-application.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:core-services.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:core-messages.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can define multiple properties files using XML configuration with this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties, ${external.prop.file.path}"/>
```

If we use JavaConfig wen can use this (Java 8 and onwards):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
@PropertySource("${external.prop.file.path}")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

Or this (previous to Java 8):

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
    @PropertySource("${external.prop.file.path}")
})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

BTW, in the event of a property name collision, the last source read takes precedence.

More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring), [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#xsd-schemas-context-pphc).